# "No module named 'foo'" Python error on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python

I am learning data visualization using Python, and trying to create a simple graph with random scatters. I currently have two Python files which are 'random_walk.py' and 'rw_visual.py'.

I get error messages saying "No module named random_walk",
and also "Unable to resolve 'random_walk'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module."

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and working with matplotlib.

'random_walk.py'

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk():

    def __init__(self, num_points=500):
        """Initialize attributes of a walk."""
        self.num_points = num_points

        # All walks start at (0,0).
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]
```

'rw_visual.py'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random_walk import RandomWalk

# Make a random walk, and plot the points.
rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()

plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, s=15)

plt.show()
```

These are where my files are saved.

C:\Users\foo\Desktop\python_work\project_2\rw_visual\rw_visual
C:\Users\foo\Desktop\python_work\project_2\random_walk\random_walk

I tried to combine the files under one folder, but it didn't do anything. 
I also created an `__init__.py` under 'project_2' folder, somehow at one point, error disappeared(but didn't show any graph), but now it doesn't change anything..

Comment: You'll need an `__init__.py` file in the directory but we're probably only going to be guessing with what you've given

Comment: The import module path should be added into sys.path in the file where u are importing it
Check sys.path

Comment: Could you update your question to show the folder's/file's structure?

Comment: @HelenaMartins Do you mean like where my python files are saved in my computer?

Comment: Indeed. It may sound weird, but understand your folders' structure is REALLY important to better understand problems concerning `import`. Trust me, I was facing a similar issue two hours ago :)

Comment: Ohh! Okay, I will edit and update them. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, fixed it. First of all, let's consider your folder structure looks like:

```
project_2/
|-- rw_visual/
|   |-- rw_visual.py
|
|-- random_walk/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- random_walk.py
```

Cut the folder `random_walk/`, keeping all its files. Now, find the folder `site-packages` in your Python installation directory (for me, it looks like `~\Python37\Lib\site-packages`). In here you will find all the modules you pip installed. Just paste the folder `random_walk` in here, together with your other modules.

Next, let's make your program understand what to do. In your case, something like this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random_walk import random_walk as rw

# Make a random walk, and plot the points.
r_walk = rw.RandomWalk()
r_walk.fill_walk()

plt.scatter(r_walk.x_values, r_walk.y_values, s=15)

plt.show()
```

In this `import`, you are telling Python to find the module `random_walk`, which is your folder's name. Inside it, Python will find `__init__.py` file, confirming it as a module. Now, from this folder/module, you shall select which Python file you want to use. So, `from random_walk import random_walk`, where the first random_walk refers to the folder and the second refers to the program. Now, I just used an `as rw` to make the writing of the code easier.

Now that your module is imported, you can call everything defined on it by using `rw.your_random_definition`.

Just remember: besides the structure is right, I can't tell if your code is. I assure you this will properly import your module, but since I couldn't test the code, can't assure it's working. If you face any other issue, there is 99,99% of chance it's coming from a coding error. If you need anymore help, I suggest providing a [minimal, verifiable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Wow, I thought my question left forgotten. Thank you so much for your time and effort! It is well described and I clearly understood now. It surely worked, I greatly appreciate your help. :)

Comment: No problem! Just make two or three sacrifices to the Gods of Python in exchange and it's all good!